# Sqlite dd/mm/yyyy format. How to avoid conversion?

Tags: sqlite

The program I am currently designing use the `dd/mm/yyyy` date format, while Sqlite standard format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. My program make use of quite a lot of date calculations using julianday('yyyy-mm-dd'). I know I could convert the `dd/mm/yyyy` format to `yyyy-mm-dd` by using `SUBSTR(X,Y)` manipulation or by using the code of the language I am designing the db front-end; but i wish to avoid those. Any Idea?

Comment: Usually date formatting is considered to be a UI issue.  It's considered good practice to logically separate your data store from your presentation logic.  Is there any reason you're opposed to handling the date formatting at the application level?

Comment: I thing that avoiding the implementation of a conversion might make things easier and maybe faster. I tryed  with Mysql, and It was right straightforward doing calculation like datediff(date1, date2) with the dd/mm/yyyy format. In the country I live, everything is dd/mm/yyyy formatted even though I'd prefer, myself,  yyyy/mm/dd format

Answer (score 2):

You should always store dates (and timestamps) using native date format that is provided by database engine for following reasons:

1. Native formats permit native date arithmetic functions to work.
2. Native formats permit indexes to be consistently applicable, so you can use date comparisons efficiently and use operators like BETWEEN.
3. Native formats take less space to store on disk. For SQLite, storing date as real number of days from 4174 BC or as integer number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970 takes 8 bytes. For your representation, it will take at least 10 bytes.

While SQLite does not really have true native date/datetime type (which is big omission in my opinion), it does have [3 permissible formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime): TEXT, REAL or INTEGER that are still treated (to some extent) as native datetime formats, and all advantages outlined above still apply.

When you need to display dates in your application, you should use libraries provided by your scripting or other programming languages that know how to display dates in desired format.

In other words, use database to store, compare and retrieve data, and use your application to render it in desired format.